# ViewPager Swipe with Button OnTouchListener event

Tags: android, android-layout, android-viewpager

I have a `ViewPager` with 2 items into it and a `Button` for `ViewPager Animation` . I wanted to swipe the `ViewPager` with the TouchEvent of Button without moving my finger up i.e Sliding my finger from Button & getting the ViewPager Swipe

Currently I am able to get A swipe only when I move Up my finger & swipe  not on the `TouchEvent`

Below is My code Snippets...of XML

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/slide_btn_speak"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:background="@android:drawable/ic_btn_speak_now"
    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/slide_txtView_inside"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/slide_btn_speak"
    android:text="@string/app_name" />

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/ui_pager"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/slide_btn_speak"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/slide_btn_speak"
    android:scrollbars="horizontal" >

</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/slide_btn_drag"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:background="@android:drawable/ic_btn_speak_now"
    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name" />
```

My Activity Snippets...

```
public class SlidingActitvity extends Activity {

    ViewPager viewPager;

    Button slide_button_start ; 

    Vibrator vibrator;

    static int count ;

    int x_position, y_position;

    String hint[] ={" SWIPE TO CANCEL " , ""};
    @Override

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sliding_actitvity);

        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.ui_pager);

        vibrator = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);

        slide_button_start = (Button) findViewById(R.id.slide_btn_drag);



        slide_button_start.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {


                switch (event.getAction()) {

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

                    int viewPager_width = viewPager.getWidth();

                    x_position = (int) event.getX();
                    y_position = (int) event.getY();
                    if(x_position<= 0){

                        vibrator.cancel();
                        viewPager.bringToFront();

                        logIt("Touch..." +x_position +"..."+y_position);
                    }

                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

                    vibrator.vibrate(100);

                    final Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(SlidingActitvity.this, R.anim.left);

                    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(SlidingActitvity.this , hint);

                    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

                    viewPager.setVisibility(ViewPager.VISIBLE);

                    viewPager.setAnimation(animation);


                    logIt("Touch...Down");

                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

                     logIt("Touch...Up");
                     vibrator.cancel();

                     break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_OUTSIDE:
                    logIt("Your are out...");
                    vibrator.cancel();
                break ;
                default:
                    break;
                }

                return true;
            }
        });

    }
```

Any Answer is Appreciated...

Comment: use method viewPager.setCurrentItem() method on button click event

Comment: @BirajZalavadia I want to swipe the Viewpager as I move from Button to ViewPager without taking my finger up...but I not getting the Swipe onthe TouchEvent on Button

Answer (score 0):

By returning true in the button's OnTouchListener, [you're consuming the touch event](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html#onTouch%28android.view.View,%20android.view.MotionEvent%29). Specifically, the ViewPager needs to be informed of `MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN` so that it can intercept touch events when it detects that it is being swiped.

You will need to carefully consider in which cases touch events get passed up the view hierarchy such that the ViewPager can continue to perform its magic.

Comment: Even If I return false to OnTouchListener & return true to only the EVENT I need to work with It's not atAll detecting the ViewPager swipe when I move my finger from Button to ViewPager